# How to filter a QuerySet with relation fields compared to a (dynamic) list

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a Requests Model which has a one-to-many relation to its RequestDetails. I also have a RequestFilter that has a one-to-one relation to the `auth.user`. What i'm trying to do is to display all Requests in a generic ListView, which have at least one RequestDetail that has a category enabled by the RequestFilter settings. I tried to accomplish this in different ways but still end up with a **"Relation fields do not support nested lookups" Error**. Here is what I did:

Given Models:

A User specifies the Requests (not django user.request) he wants to receive in a settings menu based on the following RequestFilter Model:

```
class RequestFilter(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    category1_enabled = models.BooleanField(...)
    category2_enabled = models.BooleanField(...)
    category3_enabled = models.BooleanField(...)
    ...
    def get_categories_enabled(self):
        returns a list of category names which are set to True e.g. ['category1', 'category3']
```

The Requests themselves contain basic information and a reference code:

```
class Requests(models.Model):
    request_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, ...)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    some_general_info = models.CharField(...)
    ...
```

One Request can have many RequestDetails (like Orders which have many Products)

```
class RequestDetail(models.Model):
    request = models.ForeignKey(Requests, to_field='request_id', related_name='details')
    product_id = models.IntegerField()
    category_id = models.IntegerField()
    ...
    def get_category_name:
        returns the name of the category of the RequestDetail e.g. 'category3'
```

I have a generic class based ListView which should display all Requests that contain at least one RequestDetail that is of a category which the User has set to enabled in the settings (RequestFilter).

views.py

```
class DashManagerRequestsView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/dashmanagerrequests.html'
    context_object_name = 'request_list'

    def get_categories_enabled(self):
        return self.request.user.requestfilter.get_categories_enabled()

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Returns all requests as an ordered list."""
        requestfilter_list = self.get_categories_enabled()
        return Requests.objects.order_by('-date_add').filter(details__get_category_name__in=requestfilter_list)

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(DashManagerRequestsView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

I also tried using an F() expression but this doesn't work because it only compares the values of two different fields on the SAME model instance. The closest I got was to get a list of the enabled categories for the user and lookup if the category name is a part of this list with:

`return Requests.objects.order_by('-date_add').filter(details__get_category_name__in=requestfilter_list)`

but this raises a **Relation fields do not support nested lookups Error**.

Comment: Include the get_category model and it's relationships with the other models.

Comment: Im not sure if I get what you are proposing. For the RequestDetail i get the category name via `def get_category_name:` and from the RequestFilter usersettings i get a list of enabled category names via `def get_categories_enabled:` isn't this enough to filter the Requests queryset since i can relate to the RequestDetails?

Comment: You can't use a model method in a QuerySet filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to schillingt, who pushed me into the right direction i came up with a solution.

since it is not possible to use model methods for filtering a QuerySet i generate a list of allowed ids during execution outside the filter function by relating to the RequestDetail model method using a second for loop. of course this can also be done using a list comprehension or something like that:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Requests.objects.order_by('-ps_date_add')
    request_ids = []
    for request in queryset:
        for detail in request.details.all():
            if detail.get_category_name() in self.get_categories_enabled():
                request_ids.append(request.id)
    q = q.filter(id__in=request_ids)
    return q
```

this may not be the best solution in terms of efficiency if it comes to large amounts of data.